# Why am I getting a "Microsoft JScript compilation error '800a03ee' Expected ')'" when everything is ok bracket-wise?

Tags: asp-classic

I am getting this error message even though I have checked this at least ten times and can't find anything wrong with the line of code?

```
Microsoft JScript compilation error '800a03ee'

Expected ')'

/functions.asp, line 153

if(    (   (
                (arrStory[i]['Date']).substr( (arrStory[i]['Date'])00.length - 4)
            ) 
            == intYear
        ) 
        || 
        (
            (arrStory[i]['Date']).substr(   (arrStory[i]['Date']).length - 4) == (intYear + 1)
        )
  )
--------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this:

```
arrStory[i]['Date'])00.length
```

supposed to mean?  That's not valid JScript... those zeros look like bogus extra characters to me.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. I inherited this code, and I'm not an ASP or a JScript guy. I'll look into it though.

Comment: Sure enough that was it. I don't know why those were placed there, but removing made everything work just fine. Thanks!